# Firebase return multiple objects

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am using firebase and in below query `extand()` is a function that concatenate the objects. Can some one help me to remove `$timeout` from my query ?

currently i am waiting for my `playerList` to fill.

```
var getJoinedPlayers = function(gameId){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var playerList = {};
        var usersRef = new Firebase(FBURL+'users');
        var gameRef = new Firebase(self.firebaseURL);
        var gamePlayersRef = gameRef.child(gameId).child("players");
        gamePlayersRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {
          usersRef.child(snap.key()).once("value", function(data) {
            playerList[snap.key()] = extend({'playerId': snap.key()},data.val());
            })
        });
        $timeout(function() {
          if (playerList) {
            deferred.resolve(playerList);
          } else {
            reason = {'message': "player Not found"};
            deferred.reject(reason);
          }
        }, 1300);

      return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simplify this by replacing "child_added" with "value". This will return the list of players, which you could iterate over with regular JS.
Then call

usersRef.child(snap.key()).once("value", function(data)

for each of of the items in the result, and push each of these promises into an array

```
promiseArray.push(usersRef.child(snap.key()).once("value", function(data)...
```

then you could

```
$q.all(promiseArray).then(...
```

that will combine all promises into a single promise